# Liskov Substitution Principle 4 questions

Tags: design-patterns, liskov-substitution-principle

I am finding it very difficult to understand this concept. I had a couple of questions in my mind about it. I've tried checking online but there's not much resources out there about it.

Does the subclass need to retain its distinctiveness throughtout its entire life?

I am pretty sure that LSP defines a contract between a super and a sub class, correct me if i am wrong.

What if a given function uses some object, can you replace the object with one of it's sub classes without breaking it's execution?

Will the program still work if there is a variable whose type is a super class. If I place an instance of that super class or any of the sub classes into that variable.

I am sorry if this didnt make sense. These 4 questions are bothering me about LSP.

Thank you very much

Comment: I'm pretty sure https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle answers all these questions. Did you read it?

Comment: Oh god, Liskov, I had some discussions about it longer ago. Maybe https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ will be a better place to ask this. Check [this out](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/search?q=liskov).

Comment: ive tried looking at them but found it no help

Answer (score 0):

LSP:  If `S` is a subclass of `T`, then every instance of `S` is an instance of `T`.

That's it, really, but it has implications.

I don't know what you mean by subclasses "retaining their distinctiveness".

LSP does imply that subclass instances must adhere to the superclass contract, but it's really about what it *means* when you use `S` or `T` in other contracts.

For instance, if you write a function `Number add(Number a, Number b)` that is supposed to add two numbers, then LSP says that what this really means is that it can add any instance of `Number` to any other instance of `Number`, and that *includes* instances of any subclass.  LSP says that this function *cannot* be correct otherwise, because there is nothing it can *know* about every instance of `Number` that isn't true for Integers, Floats, BigDecimals, etc., because those are *all* instances of `Number`.

> What if a given function uses some object, can you replace the object
>   with one of it's sub classes without breaking it's execution?

If this is a *parameter*, and you cannot, then the function isn't correct, or the subclass isn't correct.

> Will the program still work if there is a variable whose type is a
>   super class. If I place an instance of that super class or any of the
>   sub classes into that variable

Not necessarily.  Just because the variable is of type `Integer`, that doesn't mean you can set it to `625` arbitrarily and expect the program to continue working.  `625` is an `Integer` just like every `S` is a `T`